# JQuery Sortable is not working with div and images

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a web page which have fixed layout. Here is my Html,

**html**

```
<div id="sortable" style="display: block;">   
    <fieldset style="float: left;">
         <table>
             <tbody>
                 <tr>               
                     <td><a href="#"><img src="Data/Images/2012_08_12_00_47_53_4753.jpg" style="border-color:#DDDDDD;border-width:2px;border-style:solid;width:50px;margin-left: 10px"></a></td>
                     <td><a href="#"><img src="Data/Images/2012_08_12_00_47_54_4754.png" style="border-color:White;border-width:2px;border-style:solid;width:50px;margin-left: 10px"></a></td>
                     <td><a href="#"><img src="Data/Images/2012_08_12_00_47_55_4755.jpg" style="border-color:White;border-width:2px;border-style:solid;width:50px;margin-left: 10px"></a></td>
                     <td><a href="#"><img src="Data/Images/2012_08_12_00_47_56_4756.jpg" style="border-color:White;border-width:2px;border-style:solid;width:50px;margin-left: 10px"></a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</div>​
```

Now on my page I want to include jquery sortable option. I tried but failed. Here is what I have tried:

**jQuery**

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable();​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JXqst/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to change ur js like this

```
$( "#sortable table tr" ).sortable();​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JXqst/1/)

Comment: @user960567 you have to put all of your td in single tr to work them up-down.

Comment: I cannot chnage the layout. I just want reorder.

Answer (score 2):

here is what you want buddy.

refer [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JXqst/2/).

as you are sorting the `td` your `tr` should have the id as `sortable`

Comment: @rahul has also suggested a good way. if you are willing to change the js then it is also a good option.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use list instead table. Then you can use this:

```
function setSortableDefault(list) 
{
    $(list).sortable({ opacity: 0.6, cursor: 'move', update: function() {
        var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&action=updateRecordsListings'; 
        $.post("sortDefault.php", order, function(theResponse){
            //$("#result").html(theResponse);
        });                                                              
    }                                 
    });
}
```

This function set list defined as *list* sortable, when you moving element, it becomes a little bit transparent, prepare order and do some PHP script (here sortDefault.php). It's typical example of script using to sort elements in interface and database.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change my page layout

Answer (score 1):

`Sortable` have som parameter you can pass.

you can do it by target the `tr` element

```
$("tr", "#sortable" ).sortable();
```

Or for more performance and a restriction on `td` element

```
$("tr", "#sortable" ).sortable({
    items: "td"
});​
```

I have update your jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DoubleYo/JTmrT/

Comment: You can connect the two tr whith `connectWith: "#sortable tr"` http://jsfiddle.net/DoubleYo/x4bGA/

Comment: Thanks. But I need the position should reoder. For example, If I drag Image1 on Image 5 then Image1 position will become 5 and Image5 position will become 1

Comment: don't use `table` for this use `ul` and `li` http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid